# What's the best performance SQL database for data storage on CentOS 246MB RAM, Apache and PHP?

Tags: sql-server, linux, performance, nosql, centos

What's the best performance SQL database for data storage on CentOS **246MB RAM**, Apache and PHP, json_encode() with using **less RAM as possible**?

Maybe some [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database, [UnQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnQL)?

On right now I use MySQL, but 246MB RAM might be to little.

Performance needed on selecting multiple tables, speed on reading data, not so much writings in db.

Comment: if you have cared about performance you would have bought more RAM.

Comment: Agred, yi_H. The more memory you give the database, the more data it can cache and the less it has to read from the physical disk.

Comment: _"This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors"_ => WTF, how about helping the guy who asked the question!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replace MySQL => [Tune it](http://4rapiddev.com/mysql/tips-for-tuning-and-optimizing-mysql-on-low-memory-dedicated-server-or-vps/) for a low memory env.

You can use a simple [MySQL tuner script](http://4rapiddev.com/mysql/how-to-tune-and-optimize-mysql-performance-with-mysqltuner/) to help you understand what "parts" of MySQL are used on the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add RAM for whatever reason, I would give [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) a try. SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

Comment: Here is an article "MySQL vs SQLite3 performance" with suggestion to not to use SQLite3 in production http://zenadmin.org/en/blog/post720.html